# Oracle SQL Developer Error - ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: oracle

This is my code after check syntax this error appear

> Error at line 15, column 6: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

What problem on this code?

```sql
SELECT ahli.mshp_no, 
       branch.branch_code, 
       branch.branch_name, 
       l_mshp_type.mshp_type_desc, 
       ahli.name, 
       l_idtype.description, 
       ahli.ic_no, 
       ahli.birth_date, 
       ahli.addr_1, 
       ahli.addr_2, 
       ahli.addr_3, 
       ahli.postcode, 
       l_state.description, 
       ahli.notelru, 
       ahli.h_phone, 
       ahli.hubaddr_1, 
       ahli.hubaddr_2, 
       ahli.hubaddr_3, 
       ahli.hubpostcode, 
       ahli.emp_code, 
       ahli.offaddr_1, 
       ahli.offaddr_2, 
       ahli.offaddr_3, 
       ahli.offpostcode, 
       ahli.offaddr_4, 
       waris.nama, 
       waris.id_type, 
       waris.id_no, 
       waris.relation, 
       waris.addr_1, 
       waris.addr_2, 
       waris.addr_3, 
       waris.postcode, 
       waris.addr_4, 
       waris.no_tel1, 
       waris.no_tel2, 
       waris.mshp_no, 
       ahli.mshp_type, 
       ahli.branch_code, 
       ahli.id_type, 
       ahli.addr_4 
FROM   ahli 
       inner join waris 
               ON ahli.mshp_no = waris.mshp_no 
                  AND inner 
       join branch 
         ON ahli.branch_code = branch.branch_code 
            AND inner 
       join l_mshp_type 
         ON ahli.mshp_code = l_mshp_type.mshp_type_desc 
            AND inner 
       join l_idtype 
         ON ahli.id_type = l_idtype.description 
            AND inner 
       join l_state 
         ON ahli.offaddr_4 = l_state.description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN WARIS ON AHLI.MSHP_NO = WARIS.MSHP_NO AND
INNER JOIN
```

You have an extra "AND" at the end.

Remove those, just do

```
INNER JOIN WARIS ON AHLI.MSHP_NO = WARIS.MSHP_NO
INNER JOIN
```